# react native edit file after build

Tags: android, ios, react-native

Is there any way to edit a json file after the app was build? I heard that an apk file can be unzipped, but how about IOS? My goal is to make an app that can be changed by a non-programmer, after it was finished. Adding assets would be also good, but I don't think I would be possible.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this is possible as one would have to repackage it and sign it using the production certificate/keystore to be accepted by either Apple or Google. What you could do is include the Firebase Remote Config module which lets you define variables and their values on the Firebase console and retrieve them dynamically inside your app. This would allow the "non-programmers" to edit image URLs and other content you decide to make available.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible to achieve. There are some services around that provide something calles "on the air updates", like Microsoft Code Push. This kind of services basically changes the js bundle after the app is installed, in a way that you don't have to reinstall the apk from the store to get a new update. If you implement something similar, you can achieve that. All you have to do is edit the js bundle at runtime. I don't know exactly how to achieve that, but it is possible.
It is important to note that this updates are not applicable to the native code (Java/kotlin files on android or Objective-C/Swift files on iOS)

You can check how microsoft implemented it here:
https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-code-push